# How to select Input|Output Cell Groups in the Notebook?

Tags: front-end, programming, notebooks, cells

I am trying to convert a Cell expression to an image.

I created a new notebook and copied the cells that need to be rendered.

```
nb = CreateDocument[{},
    WindowSelected -> False, Visible -> True,
    WindowSize -> 650, StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"
];
(*Find and Copy the Cell Groups*)
image = Rasterize[nb, "Image"]
```

I want to automate this process now,finding all the Input|Output groups and render.

---

A Input|Output Group should be defined from Input to the last GeneratedCell, including Print, Message, etc.

[image]

Cell Style "Code" and "Program" also have Output, but I hope to eliminate them.

Comment: Do you care about `In[]/Out[]`? or only about contents?

Comment: Yes,best to keep, I think it's Useful and beautiful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me know if this fits your needs:

```
rasterizeInOut[nb_NotebookObject] := Module[{printNb, image, cells},
  printNb = CreateDocument[{}, Visible -> False];
  cells = Cells[nb, CellStyle -> {"Input"}];
  cells = Flatten[
    If[ 
      Lookup[Developer`CellInformation[#], "FirstCellInGroup"], 
      SelectionMove[#, All, CellGroup]; SelectedCells[nb], 
      #
    ] & /@ cells
  ];
  NotebookWrite[printNb, #] & /@ NotebookRead /@ cells;
  image = Rasterize @ printNb;
  NotebookClose @ printNb;
  image
]

rasterizeInOut @ nb
```

On the left there is a source nb and on the right an image generated from filtered source:

[image]

Comment: Nice, this works. One more question, is it possible to insert an `In[ ]` when there only one input cell in notebook.For example, run itself in one cell: `rasterizeInOut@EvaluationNotebook[]`

Comment: Strange it is not included, will try to take a closer look later.